# How to authenticate with OAuth to access EWS APIs

Tags: c#, oauth, exchangewebservices

My web service is currently doing basic username/password authentication in order to subscribe the exchange user for receiving the events (like new mail event etc) like below:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(exchangeVersion)
                                  {
                                      KeepAlive = true,
                                      Url = new Uri("some autodiscovery url"),
                                      Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
                                  };

var subscription = service.SubscribeToPushNotifications(
                                    new[] { inboxFolderFoldeID },
                                    new Uri("some post back url"),
                                    15,
                                    null,
                                    EventType.NewMail,
                                    EventType.Created,
                                    EventType.Deleted,
                                    EventType.Modified,
                                    EventType.Moved,
                                    EventType.Copied);
```

Now, I am supposed to replace the authentication mechanism to use OAuth protocol. I saw some examples but all of them seem to be talking about authenticating the client (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but nowhere I was able to find an example of how to authenticate an exchange user with OAuth protocol. Any code sample will help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing that came up while investigating oauth for EWS, is it only available for office 365 and not for exchange servers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761(v=exchg.150).aspx says that "OAuth authentication for EWS is only available in Exchange as part of Office 365. EWS applications require the "Full access to user's mailbox" permission."

Comment: unfortunately none of the links talks about how to get it to work with EWS managed API. The msdn url I posted in the question does not seem to authenticate the user but just authorizing the client it seems

Comment: Have you looked at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ronba/2016/05/09/using-powershell-and-the-office-365-rest-api-with-oauth/ ?

Comment: yes, but this seems to be based on REST APIs and I want to use EWS manged APIs if possible. But if not, I guess this would be my last option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone is still struggling to get it to work. We need to upload a certificate manifest on azure portal for the application and then use the same certificate to authenticate the client for getting the access token. For more details please see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/

Comment: Hi @tavier, I am wondering if you can help me with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429701/why-app-is-throwing-error-in-test-environment-but-working-fine-in-local-machine

Comment: Kind of inconvenient to do if those certificates keep expiring each quarter.

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear what you mean with 'web service' and how you currently get the username and password. If that is some kind of website where the user needs to login or pass credentials, then you'll have to start an OAuth2 grant from the browser as in redirecting the clients browser to the authorize endpoint to start [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) or [code grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1). The user will be presented a login screen on the OAuth2 server (and not in your application), once the user logs in a code or access token (depending on the grant) will be returned to your application which you can use in the `ExchangeService` constructor.

If that 'web' service is some service that runs on the users computer you can use one of the methods described below.

**Get AccessToken using AuthenticationContext**

The example seems to be based on an older version of the [`AuthenticationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretoken.aspx) class.

The [other version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext?view=azure-dotnet) seems to be newer, also the `AcquireToken` is now renamed to `AcquireTokenAsync` / `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`.

No matter which version you're using, you will not be able to pass username and password like you're doing in your current code. However, you can let the `AcquireToken[Async]` method prompt for credentials to the user. Which, let's be honest, is more secure then letting your application deal with those user secrets directly. Before you know, you'll be storing plain text passwords in a database (hope you aren't already).

In both versions, those methods have a lot of overloads all with different parameters and slightly different functionality. For your use-case I think these are interesting:

- New: [`AcquireTokenAsync(string, string, Uri, IPlatformParameters)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Uri_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_IPlatformParameters_) where `IPlatformParameters` could be `new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)`
- Old: [`AcquireToken(string, string, Uri, PromptBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479460.aspx) where prompt behavior could be `PromptBehavior.Auto`

Prompt behavior auto, in both vesions, means: *the user will be asked for credentials when they're not already cached*. Both `AuthenticationContext` constructors allow you to pass a token-cache which is something you can implement yourself f.e. to cache tokens in memory, file or database (see [this article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/09/the-new-token-cache-in-adal-v2/) for an example file cache implementation).

**Get AccessToken manually**

If you really want to pass in the user credentials from code without prompting the user, there is always a way around. In this case you'll have to implement the [Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) as outlined in OAuth2 specificatioin / RFC6749.

Coincidence or not, I have an open-source library called [`oauth2-client-handler`](https://github.com/huysentruitw/oauth2-client-handler) that implements this for use with `HttpClient`, but anyway, if you want to go this route you can dig into that code, especially starting from [this method](https://github.com/huysentruitw/oauth2-client-handler/blob/master/src/OAuth2ClientHandler/Authorizer/Authorizer.cs#L58).

**Use Access Token**

Once you have an access token, you can proceed with the samples on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), f.e.:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(exchangeVersion)
                  {
                      KeepAlive = true,
                      Url = new Uri("some autodiscovery url"),
                      Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken))
                  };
```

Comment: That answers many questions I had, thanks :) but the thing is, in order to get rid of dealing with the password of the user, we wanted to implement oauth (that's what my understanding of oauth is), so is it possible to completely do away with the username and password authentication of the user and authenticate the user with the access token? I read something related to impersonation of users but did not get a good sample code to fit into my requirement.

Comment: Also, ExchangeService object seems to have a property called ImpersonatedUserId does it mean I can impersonate that particular user and subscribe him for notifications. I guess not but just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, actually my application is a Web API with some endpoints (without any UI) to which user from some email clients will be passing his credentials (this is the current flow), however, we would like to remove the need of him passing the password if possible.

Comment: Don't know how that ImpersonatedUserId works, but I guess if you have enough access rights it could be used to impersonate as a different user. In the other case you'll have to start a OAuth2 grant to get an access token. Depending on the identity provider, there might already be an OWIN authentication middleware for it that you can use.

Comment: Okay, I have provided my application permission to "access mailboxes as signed in user via exchange web service" so it should be allowed to impersonate the user right? I would try setting the ImpersonatedUserId  and see if I am able to subscribe the user without passing the username and password. Thanks

Comment: while trying to acquire the token (with PromptBehavior set to Never), I get "oauth user_interaction_required: One of two conditions was encountered: 1. The PromptBehavior.Never flag was passed, but the constraint could not be honored, because user interaction was required. 2. An error occurred during a silent web authentication that prevented the http authentication flow from completing in a short enough time frame"

Comment: I am confused why it requires the user credentials to get the app token.

Comment: So I am able to get the app token with await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("hettps://outlook.office365.com", new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret)); But I get 401 (Unauthorized) when I try to use the token to subscribe the user for push notfication (by setting the userid in ImpersonatedUserId  property of the service.

Comment: Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614307/401-unauthorized-while-subscribing-to-push-notifications-with-exchange-service-a

Answer (score 2):

Using the example code in this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth) as the starting point and these libraries:

- Microsoft Identity Client 4.27
- EWS Managed API v2.2

I am able to successfully authenticate and connect with Exchange on Office 365.

```
      public void Connect_OAuth()
      {
         var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
               .Create          ( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "appId" ] )
               .WithClientSecret( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "clientSecret" ] )
               .WithTenantId    ( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "tenantId" ] )
               .Build();

         var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

         AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

         try
         {
            authResult = cca.AcquireTokenForClient( ewsScopes ).ExecuteAsync().Result;
         }
         catch( Exception ex )
         {
            Console.WriteLine( "Error: " + ex );
         }

         try
         {
            var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();

            ewsClient.Url                = new Uri( "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx" );
            ewsClient.Credentials        = new OAuthCredentials( authResult.AccessToken );
            ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId( ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "ccc@pppsystems.co.uk" );

            ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add( "X-AnchorMailbox", "ccc@pppsystems.co.uk" );


            var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders( WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView( 10 ) );

            foreach( var folder in folders )
            {
               Console.WriteLine( "" + folder.DisplayName );
            }
         }
         catch( Exception ex )
         {
            Console.WriteLine( "Error: " + ex );
         }
      }
```

The Microsoft example code did not work - the async call to `AcquireTokenForClient` never returned.

By calling `AcquireTokenForClient` in a separate `try` `catch` block catching a general `Exception`, removing the `await` and using `.Result`, this now works - nothing else was changed.

I realise that this is not best practice but, both with and without the debugger, the async call in the original code never returned.

In the Azure set-up:

- A client secret text string was used - a x509 certificate was not necessary
- The configuration was 'app-only authentication'

Hope this helps someone avoid hours of frustration.

Comment: I like your answer. I am wondering if you help me with my issue. I am using delegated authentication in my app which is Asp.net Webform using .net framework 4.5 and VB.NET as language. I can run this in Visual Studio but when I deploy in IIS I get error: "Showing modal/form when the app is not running in UserInteractive mode is not valid". For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429701/why-app-is-throwing-error-in-test-environment-but-working-fine-in-local-machine

Comment: @AvishekhBharati - your issue MAY be related. From the above answer, with some combinations of MSAL, .NET etc (that is probably version related), there is a multi-threading issue where the authentication token is not returned. What I have effectively done is to make the async call (non-blocking) into a sync call (blocking). Looking at your question 1) you are using a fairly early version of .NET 2) you have still got the async call.