# Can token returned from mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync perform write action on mail item

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-web-addins

From this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5&view=office-js#getcallbacktokenasync) we can use `getCallbackTokenAsync` to get a token with which we can use it to call the Exchange Web Services in a third party system.
The quote is "Gets a string that contains a token used to get an attachment or item from an Exchange Server." It does not specify any limitation on the "write" permission.

Then, according to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions), if we change the add-in permission to `ReadWriteMailbox`, we can "Read and write all properties of any item in the user's mailbox."

In my add-in I have the permission level set to `ReadWriteMailbox` and I use the token returned from `getCallbackTokenAsync` to authenticate the `exchange service`. But when I tried writing custom properties to Exchange server, I got this error `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: 'The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.'`

My code

```
exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials({accesstoken returned by mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync});
Guid PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS = new Guid("00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS, "cecp-a8e14732-37cf-4a46-b69f-2539f4059948", MapiPropertyType.String);
var obj = new
{
 customProp: "cp"
 };
Email.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
Email.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite); //this erros occurs here
```

Comment: Is it possible that your authentication is wrong.  Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415606/how-to-authenticate-with-oauth-to-access-ews-apis   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

Answer (score 1):

The token provided by getCallbackTokenAsync can be used only for the methods documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services

You can refer this link to find ways to authenticate to EWS directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange

Updating custom properties directly via EWS is not recommended and only the app should be used for that purpose.