# How to get OAuth2 access token for EWS managed API in service/daemon application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

## Scenario

I have an Exchange Online environment and service/daemin (no interactive user) application on the Azure VM. Service uses EWS managed API to work with emails in the mailbox of **any** tenant user. Now EWS client uses Basic authentication that, according to Microsoft, will become unsupported in EWS to access Exchange Online.

## Question/Issue

So, I need to find a way to get valid access token for service/daemon application to use with EWS managed API.

## My findings

The following [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth) shows an example of using OAuth 2.0 with EWS managed API. This example works, but it uses interactive method of getting consent (sign-in form appears allowing user authenticate themselves and grant requested permission to application) that is not suitable for service/daemon app scenario, because there is no interactive user.

For service/daemon application I need to use `client credential` authentication flow.

#### Registered application

Using admin account on https://aad.portal.azure.com portal I registered application with Azure Active Directory. Added client secret for registered application.

Aforementioned [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth) uses `https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All` as a `scope`. But I did not find permission with such a URL on the portal. I found only the following permissions under `Office 365 Exchange Online` > `Application permissions` > `Mail`:

1. `https://outlook.office365.com/Mail.Read` Allows the app to read mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user
2. `https://outlook.office365.com/Mail.ReadWrite`  Allows the app to create, read, update, and delete mail in all mailboxes without a signed-in user.

I added both of them and granted admin consent for all users.

#### Getting access token

For testing purposes and simplicity I did not use any auth libraries (ADAL, MSAL etc.). I used Postman to get access token, then set `token` variable in debug (see code snippet later in the post).

I tried different endpoints to get acess token.

1. **OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v2)**

```
    POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
        grant_type=client_credentials
        client_id=*** 
        client_secret=***
        scope=https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All
```

Sending this request produces the following error response:

*AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All is not valid.*

I tried changing `scope` to `https://outlook.office.com/.default`. Access token was returned, but it appeared to be invalid for EWS. EWS client throws 401 error with the following value of `x-ms-diagnostics` response header:

*2000008;reason="The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.";error_category="invalid_grant"*

2. **OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v1)**

```
    POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/token
        grant_type=client_credentials
        client_id=*** 
        client_secret=***
        resource=https://outlook.office.com
```

Access token was returned, but also appeared to be invalid for EWS. EWS client throws 401 error with the same value of `x-ms-diagnostics` response header as described ealier in #1.

### Use aquired access token with EWS managed API

Here is code sample that I used to test EWS client with access token acquired in Postman:

```cs
var token = "...";
var client = new ExchangeService
{
    Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
    Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(token),
    ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress,
                 "user@domain.onmicrosoft.com"),

};
var folder = Folder.Bind(client, WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);
```

Comment: I would assume with client credentials or certificate based auth, those are specific to the tenant. If it's the only tenant that's fine, but if you need to support a product that anyone can use to access their own tenant then you need them to do the same cert/client process, or use the sign-in process. The latter you could store a refresh token for in a service application to get access tokens. The former, I understand there's a way of providing an "application" that 365 admins can install in 365 and hook that up, but haven't looked at that yet.

Comment: Can someone confirm that is it possible or not to limit the number of mailboxes accessible for an application permissions view EWS API?

Comment: @Oleksii Have you tried connect using EWS API with client id & tenant id instead of token

Answer (score 6):

We had a similar problem: We wanted to use a Service Account to connect to a single mailbox and just doing some stuff with the EWS API (e.g. searching in the GAL) and the `full_access_as_app` seems like an overkill.
Fortunately it is possible:

1. Follow the normal ["delegate" steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth)
2. And use this to get a token via username/password:

```
...
var cred = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" }, cred.UserName, cred.SecurePassword).ExecuteAsync();
...
```

3. To make this work you **need** to enable the "Treat application as public client" under "Authentication" > "Advanced settings" because this uses the "Resource owner password credential flow". (This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018045/get-delegate-permission-in-msal-for-ews-without-publicclientapplicationbuilder-a) helped me alot!)

With that setup we could use a "tradional" username/password way, but using OAuth and the EWS API.

Comment: Why do you need `var cred = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");` ??

Comment: @T.S. (not sure why - long time ago), but I guess the `AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword` seems to need the Password maybe as a `SecureString` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can protect your client application with either a certificate or a secret.  The two permissions that I needed to get this to work were `Calendars.ReadWrite.All` and `full_access_as_app`.  I never tried acquiring my token via **PostMan**, but use `AcquireTokenAsync` in `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`.  In that call, the `resource` parameter I use is https://outlook.office365.com/.  It's pretty simple once you know all the little twists and turns.  And full disclosure: I was one lost puppy until MSFT support helped me through this.  The doc on the web is often outdated, conflicting, or at best, confusing.

Comment: Eventually, I made EWS client work as expected by grating `full_access_as_app` permission. It is located in `API permissions` > `Add a permission` > `APIs my organization uses` > `Office 365 Exchange Online` > `Application permissions` > `full_access_as_app`.

I used Postman for testing purposes.

Comment: This will allow ANY modification in ANY mailbox. This will not pass security audits in most companies and is therefore not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your app in Azure and use certificate based authentication. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2018/09/11/authenticating-against-exchange-web-services-using-certificate-based-oauth2-tokens/

Comment: Link appears to be dead.

Comment: Updated link, but answers should not be link based anyway for the reason of dead links - https://developermessaging.azurewebsites.net/2018/09/11/authenticating-against-exchange-web-services-using-certificate-based-oauth2-tokens/

Comment: You do not need to use certificate based authentication. Using a client secret text string also works. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66565310/5945199

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue while following Microsoft official docs for [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret)

According to the [Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), the scope "should be the resource identifier (application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the .default suffix" (see [default scope doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope)).

So the question is how to convert `https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All` into the resource identifier.

Experimentally I manage to make it working using `scope=https://outlook.office365.com/.default`. I granted `full_access_as_app` (Office 365 Exchange Online / Application permissions) and [got administrator consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#3-get-administrator-consent) for it.

Comment: Necroresponding, but... You can't use "resource" with "v2.0" OAUTH URIs. You can use "resource" = "https : //outlook.office365.com/" if you use these instead (removing the "v2.0"): https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize and https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

Answer (score 0):

I did face this issue while implementing OAuth for EWS. My application is ***not*** using [EWS Managed API](https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api). Here is what all I did to make it working.

1. Added permission `Office 365 Exchange Online > full_access_as_app` to application.
2. Acquired access token for scope `https://outlook.office365.com/.default`.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

form-data = {
  client_id,
  client_secret,
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  scope: 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default',
};
```

3. Added access token as `Authorization` header and `ExchangeImpersonation` SOAP header to the request.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    <t:ConnectingSID>
      <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>user@domain.com</t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
    </t:ConnectingSID>
  </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but since this seems to come up, and I was just working with this... why not.

If you use Microsoft's v2.0 URLs for OAUTH2 (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and `.../common/oauth2/v2.0/token`) then the scope for Office 365 EWS is:

`https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All`

You'll probably want to combine this scope with "openid" (to get the signed in user's identity) and "offline_access" (to get a refresh token). But then offline_access may not be necessary when using client credentials (because you don't have to prompt a human user for them every time you need an access token).

In other words:

```
params.add("client_id", "...")
...
params.add("scope", "openid offline_access https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All")
```

If using v1 OAUTH2 URLs (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` and `.../common/oauth2/token`) then you can use a "resource" instead of a "scope". The resource for Office 365 is `https://outlook.office365.com/`.

Or in other words:

```
params.add("resource", "https://outlook.office365.com/")
```

Note that in the latter case, you're not asking for any scopes (it's not possible to combine "resource" with scopes). But the token will automatically cover offline_access and openid scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method successfully:

1. Install Microsoft Authentication Library module ( MSAL.PS)
   https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSAL.PS/4.2.1.3
2. Configure Delegate Access as per MSFT instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth
3. Configure ApplicationImpersonation for a service account as normal
4. Grab your token

   $cred = Get-Credential

   $clientid = ""

   $tenantid = ""

   $tok = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientid -TenantId $tenantid -UserCredential $cred -Scopes "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All"