# EWS API to access Office365 with oAuth2

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

We have a Daemon application that uses the EWS API to access office365/Exchange server with basic authentication.   I am trying to implement the Oauth2. There are a lot of documents.  However, they are often out of date and caused more confusion. I followed this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview, which seems up-to-date.  I did the following steps:

Register App

Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-registration
-   Registered a secret with application password in Azure AD, i.e. certificate is used.  The generated secret is recorded.
-   selected the “Accounts in this organizational directory only”.
-   Requested API Permission for Application permissions for Exchange full_access_as_app and Mail.Read.   Admin consent is granted.

Get Token

Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=java
I prototyped to use Protocol to get token

```
 POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1           
 Host: login.microsoftonline.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 client_id={myAppClientId}
 &scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
 &client_secret={myAppSecret}
 &grant_type=client_credentials
```

I got token with

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 3599,
"ext_expires_in": 3599,
"access_token": "……thetoken…"
```

}

Call EWS API in my App

My App works with the Basic Authentication.  I modified it by adding the Authorization header ("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);   Basially the prepareWebRequest() function is overriden by adding the Authorization header.  Compared with a Basic Authentication case, the request has the additional Authorization header with the Bearer token.

For the same EWS API call that the Basic Authorization had worked, the response is 401 with
x-ms-diagnostics
2000003;reason="The audience claim value is invalid for current resource. Audience claim is 'https://graph.microsoft.com', request url is 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx' and resource type is 'Exchange'.";error_category="invalid_resource"

Researched in stackoverflow, people suggested to use the following as scope value to get token in step 2:
https://outlook.office365.com/full_access_as_app
https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read
I tried and both returned “invalid_scope” error. It seems both worked before but not anymore.  Following the working scope value format, I tried to use https://outlook.office.com/.default as scope value.  I was able to get a token!  However, when I use this token in EWS API to access the mailbox, I got 500 error instead of the 401.
What are the right things to do to make it work?  What is the right Scope to access an office365 mail box?

More Code Snippets

This is a new class added for oauth2

```
package microsoft.exchange.webservices.data;
import java.util.Map;
public final class BearerTokenCredentials extends ExchangeCredentials {

private static final String BEARER_TOKEN_FORMAT_REGEX = "^[-._~+/A-Za-z0-9]+=*$";
private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
private static final String BEARER_AUTH_PREAMBLE = "Bearer ";
private String token;
public String getToken() {
    return token;
}
public BearerTokenCredentials(String bearerToken) {
    if (bearerToken == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bearer token can not be null");
    }
    this.validateToken(bearerToken);
    this.token = bearerToken;
}
protected void validateToken(String bearerToken) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (!bearerToken.matches(BEARER_TOKEN_FORMAT_REGEX)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bearer token format is invalid.");
    }
}
@Override
public void prepareWebRequest(HttpWebRequest request) {
    Map<String, String> headersMap = request.getHeaders();
    String bearerValue = BEARER_AUTH_PREAMBLE + token;
    headersMap.put(AUTHORIZATION, bearerValue);
    //headersMap.put("X-AnchorMailbox","esj_office365_imap@genesyslab.onmicrosoft.com");
    request.setHeaders(headersMap);
}
```

}

Use the token to acceess EWS/Exchange ews-java-api 2.0-patched

```
ExchangeService service  = new 
ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2); //version is 
Exchange2010_SP2
service.setTraceEnabled(true);
BearerTokenCredentials credentials = new BearerTokenCredentials("thetoken");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new 
URI(host));//https://outloook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
try{
Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox); 
}catch(Exception e)
{
//The remote server returned an error: (500)Internal Server Error
}
```

Comment: `https://outlook.office.com/.default` should be the correct value for "scope" for v2.0 token endpoint. I can access 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx' with the Authorization header "Bearer {access token}". Please add more code about which endpoint you are calling.

Comment: @AllenWu Thanks a lot.  I added "More Code Snippets"

Answer (score 0):

The code you use to connect to the Office365 Mailbox still needs to use EWS Impersonation eg

```
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, mailboxName);
```

Where MailboxName is the Mailbox you want to connect to.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked.  Is there a way to prevent access to other mailboxes in the same company Exchange server?  It seems with the permission given to my application I can access all the mailboxes.

Comment: No with the Graph API you can scope the permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access but EWS at this point is a bit of legacy so you basically get full access to every mailbox.

Comment: Does MicroSoft have plan to rectify this regression behavior in EWS?  With Basic Authenticate, application can be permissted to only access one particular mailbox with its credential.  At what point will MicroSoft take care the legacy issues such as this one and IMAP with Oauth2?  It impact our business a lot:(

Comment: If you use Delegate authentication (eg you create a user give it rights to the Mailboxes you want to access etc) and authentication with that then it will behave the same way as basic authentication. Your using app only tokens which are meant for a different purpose.

Comment: The Delegate authentication with a user that you mentioned, will it still use basic authentication?  What is the correct way for our daemon application to access a mailbox and only one mailbox in an Exchange server when basic authentication is not supported in EWS?

Comment: No you use ropc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc and get the access token using the username and password for the account you created. The account you use can be the Mailbox owner or a service account you create (that will need an Office365 licence) that is granted access to the Mailbox vai Add-MailboxPermissions

Comment: I used the msal4j (1.1).  It seems PublicClientApplication is the one that I can pass in all the attributes:  client_id, client secret, scope the mailbox username and password.  I got a token.  When I try to access the EWS API, I got 500 error code.   I kept the ImpersonatedUserId, which helped to solve my previous 500 error problem.  This time should I revert the ImpersonatedUserId?

Comment: Yes you shouldn't be using the ImpersonatedUserId because you now just using the service principal. You do need to have the delegate scope in the you application registration  eg should be https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All and also make sure you set the X-AnchorMailbox header (you seem to have it commented)

Comment: Yes, it worked.  Thank you very much.  In addition to the "X-AnchorMailbox", I used the "X-PublicFolderMailbox" to solve the max concurrent connect exception problem.  Do I need keep "X-PublicFolderMailbox"?

Comment: If anyone wonder how they solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009837/how-to-get-oauth2-access-token-for-ews-managed-api-in-service-daemon-application/63175301#63175301