# EWS GetUserPhoto switch from Basic Auth to OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I have been using Basic Auth to get user photo as below.

```
string email = "SomeEmail@email.com";

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email={0}&size=HR648x648", email)) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("SomeID", "SomePwd");

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
       Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
           string encodedPhoto = Convert.ToBase64String((ms.ToArray()));
       }
}
```

But since Basic Authentication for EWS will be decommissioned, I'm trying to use OAuth 2.0 for the same request. This is what I've tried so far.

```
var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
{
     ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"],
     TenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"]
};

var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();
var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };
var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();

string email = "SomeEmail@Email.com";
ewsClient.Url = new Uri(string.Format("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email={0}&size=HR648x648", email));
ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
```

How can I proceed to get user photo from here? Any help or information will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the EWS Managed API you can just modify you existing code to include the Access token eg

```
   string email = "SomeEmail@email.com";

   HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email={0}&size=HR648x648", email)) as HttpWebRequest;
   request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);

 using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
 {
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        string encodedPhoto = Convert.ToBase64String((ms.ToArray()));
    }
 }
```

or if you do want to use the EWS managed API you can use something like

```
    String ETag = "";
    GetUserPhotoResults grPhoto = service.GetUserPhoto("user@domain.com", "HR240x240", ETag);
    if (grPhoto.Status == GetUserPhotoStatus.PhotoReturned) 
    {
        ETag = grPhoto.EntityTag; 
    }
    grPhoto = service.GetUserPhoto("user@domain.com", "HR240x240", ETag);
    switch (grPhoto.Status) 
    {
        case GetUserPhotoStatus.PhotoReturned: ETag = grPhoto.EntityTag;
            break;
        case GetUserPhotoStatus.PhotoUnchanged:
            Console.WriteLine("Photo Unchanged");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. But I have a question. Currently I'm using delegated permission to get the token, but I want to use Application Permission so that it can run without user sign-in. I tried with the guide in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth#:~:text=Configure%20for%20app-only%20authentication and it added `full_access_as_app` in API permissions, but it need admin consent. It seems way overkill to use `full_access_as_app` **just to get photo**. Is there any other way?

Comment: Using the Graph api (see the other answer) is the best way to minimize the permissions required. You could use the ROPC grant eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61018045/get-delegate-permission-in-msal-for-ews-without-publicclientapplicationbuilder-a and have your service account credentials in something like KeyVault to keep them secure.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Microsoft Graph API to get User Photo. Refer, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

Try it out using Graph Explorer

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me%2Fphoto%2F%24value&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com

Get started with Graph .Net SDK
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var stream = await graphClient.Me.Photo.Content
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```