# How can I access a mailbox with restricted permissions through EWS without interactive login?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchangewebservices

We need to read out distribution lists from a contact folder of a dedicated exchange/outlook mailbox (O365). The process must run as a service with no user interaction.

Unfortunately the Graph API does not support distribution lists (not even the Graph beta version does). Because of this we have to use another API - I tried using EWS.

I succeeded by granting full_access_as_app permission to our service. However this allows to read and modify ANY data in ANY mailbox which is a security risk. Granting this permission only to read out some distribution lists from one mailbox is not acceptable.

So I tried to use the ROPC flow that should allow authenticating a user and then accessing the mailbox with the permissions of this user. I followed the information here: [How to get OAuth2 access token for EWS managed API in service/daemon application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009837/how-to-get-oauth2-access-token-for-ews-managed-api-in-service-daemon-application/63175301#63175301)

(Btw I found this post linked in the discussion here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/5659 which has some more information about the topic.)

I exactly followed the steps mentioned above but unfortunately this is not working: I always get a “401 Unauthorized” exception when doing the EWS calls (OAuth calls succeed) and no additional information.

According to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ this is no longer working. So how can I read out distribution lists from a specific mailbox without giving full access and without an interactive login?

***EDIT***
Here as requested the full code:

```
string[] ewsScopes = { "https://outlook-tdf-2.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

IPublicClientApplication clientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId).WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId).Build();
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(appUsername, appPassword);

AuthenticationResult authResult = await clientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(ewsScopes, credentials.UserName, credentials.SecurePassword).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService
{
    Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
    Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
};

ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue)
{
    PropertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Id),
};
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Contact");

FindItemsResults<Item> ewsResult = await exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, filter, view).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I have also tried with other scopes such as "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" or "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" but without success. I feel the problem might be related to the scope? I can see that the Exchange legacy API that was listed in the Azure UI when adding permissions is now gone...?

Comment: ROPC will work fine but it sounds like you a little confused as to how it works eg your linking to Application permission which is the user credentials flow, for ROPC you need to use Delegate permissions and make sure you application registration is marked as public and it should work fine. You should post the code you using which make it easier to understand and point out what you doing wrong in this instance.

Comment: @GlenScales I have followed exactly the steps described in the first SO link. You can find all the code when checking the link (and the link in the linked page).

Comment: There's a mix of different answers in that link which one do you use, I use ROPC with EWS all the time so I'm trying to help you work out what it wrong but need more information.

Comment: @GlenScales I do the setup according to the MS documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth (delegated setup only of course! I do the registrations exactly as described there and use 1:1 the code at the bottom). Then I do the two changes mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57009837/how-to-get-oauth2-access-token-for-ews-managed-api-in-service-daemon-application/63175301#63175301

Comment: have you checked the access token in https://jwt.io/ look specifically at the audience and scope

Comment: @GlenScales I did and everything looks ok. The only suspicious thing I notice is that the scope is https://outlook-tdf-2.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All and not the one used in the example code. Could that be the problem? If yes, how to fix it? If no, are you sure the example should still work because of https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ ?

Comment: If the scope in your request was https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All then in your Token the aud value should be https://outlook.office365.com/ and the scp value should be EWS.AccessAsUser.All . The blog you refer to is about the removal of Basic authentication which has no affect on OAuth (other then requiring people to switch to it). I would capture the Token request with something like fiddler to verify what you actually sending to the server, it would help if you post your actual code as well

Comment: @GlenScales Ok interesting. But then why is the option to add the Exchange Legacy permission (step 6 in the MS docu mentioned above) gone from the Azure UI?

Comment: @GlenScales I have added the code. Please note that appId is the guid of the app registration and appUsername/appPassword is an ordinary user in the AD.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday Nov 19th Microsoft has updated the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

Following the new documentation it works (again). The main difference is to use the shortened scope "EWS.AccessAsUser.All" and not any of the full scopes found in many examples and posts such as “https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All”, “https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All” etc.

Thank you MS for wasting my time.

Answer (score 1):

The Scope in your code is wrong (I'm not sure where you got that from) it should be

```
string[] ewsScopes = { "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };
```

Using your code with the scope you had gives a 401 error and if you look at the response headers of the EWS response it actually tells you that the scope is the issue eg

```
2000003;reason="The audience claim value is invalid for current resource. Audience claim is 'https://outlook-tdf-2.office.com/', request url is 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx' and resource type is 'Exchange'.";error_category="invalid_resource"
```

Using your code with the correct scope works fine

> > But then why is the option to add the Exchange Legacy permission (step 6 in the MS docu mentioned above) gone from the Azure UI?

Its hasn't been removed from the AzureUI they have just moved all the Exchange legacy permissions (including the ones used in the Exchange Admin cmdlets which isn't really a legacy API) under the Graph Permissions. Why they did this way and didn't communicate it well (I'll only just saw it today as well) I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you Glen for all your answers! It kept me trying and allowed me to finally find the answer. However your suggestion doesn't work for me - as I said already I tried a number of scopes including the one you suggested and neither of them worked - only the solution in the new MS documentation I have posted now does. I will upvote some of your comments to reward you in some way.

Comment: That might make hybrid modern authentication interesting as the audience (OnPrem) is derived from the scope. But i would agree this is pretty poor on Microsoft's behalf eg is that a breaking change for anybody who used the other format or was this something specific in just your scenario and what happens in Hybrid Modern Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Distribution groups are only exposed in Exchange PowerShell today, and are not currently supported via the Microsoft Graph API.

Please vote on this feature request on [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38178205-list-members-from-exchange-dynamic-distribution-gr):

Comment: You can automate the Exchange powershell with .Net as well. Here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/development/develop-apps-by-using-exchange-powershell

Comment: There are a number of feature requests for this: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/6173709-provide-a-way-to-create-a-distribution-group https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/39346507-allow-retrieval-of-contact-lists the one you listed and probably more. I voted for all of them already but not sure anyone has an overview over this and realizes that it all refers to the same distibution list support...