# EWS error for OAuth 2 token The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to access EWS using OAuth 2 but I am getting an error **The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized**

I successfully received Access/Refresh Token

Here adding a token to the ExchangeService

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService("Exchange2010_SP1");
service.getHttpHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer " + "some token");
service.setUrl("_serviceURI");

service.findFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts, new FolderView(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

nowhere I got an error **The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized**

what I am doing wrong here?

following is my authorize URL

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=client_id
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:80800/api/
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid offline_access https://outlook.office365.com/.default 
&state=12345
```

Comment: If you look at the Token in https://jwt.io/ what scopes do you see? for EWS with Delegate access the only valid scope is EWS.AccessAsUser.All

Comment: @GlenScales yes, I have the same scope

Comment: You could try the shorten scope as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64871100/how-can-i-access-a-mailbox-with-restricted-permissions-through-ews-without-inter/64921453#comment114783288_64921453 (the full works for me but they seem to be having a similar issue to yourself)

Comment: @GlenScales thank for the informtion :)

Comment: @GlenScales now it is giving different error 
{"code":"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
"message":"The tenant for tenant guide"'}

Comment: that indicates your tenant id (or if your using a domain the domain) isn't correct how did you retrieve it ?