# Exchange EWS with delegate, debugger stops after getting authenticationresult

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TicketSync ts = new TicketSync();
            ts.ScanMailBox();
        }
```

```
private async void ScanMailBox()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_mailboxToOpen)) return;

            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            try
            {
                // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0

                // Configure the MSAL client to get tokens
                var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = "*clientGuid*",
                    TenantId = "*TenantGuid*"
                };

                var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                    .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

                // The permission scope required for EWS access
                var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("***@***.eu", "*******");

                AuthenticationResult authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(ewsScopes, credentials.UserName, credentials.SecurePassword).ExecuteAsync();
```

when i get to that last line my debugger just stops running, no error, even though there is a try catch around it all, even tried adding a try catch around that line solely, but nothing works.  Any idea why this is happening?

application is an automated service that would have to check a mailbox periodically using set credentials.  i followed these solutions so far:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth
[How can I access a mailbox with restricted permissions through EWS without interactive login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64871100/how-can-i-access-a-mailbox-with-restricted-permissions-through-ews-without-inter)

Answer (score 0):

okay, i figured it out myself.  I added this to the code:

```
var task = pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(ewsScopes, credentials.UserName, credentials.SecurePassword).ExecuteAsync();
                while(!task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    task.Wait(10000);
                }
                var authResult = task.Result;
```

this gave me the actual error at first, altho the website stated admin consent was not necessary for user access, it was necessary.  hooray.

after fixing this error it worked.  So the wait was necessary for it to work and to show the error